# Sort Core Data results on a string attributes length

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nssortdescriptor

so basically like the title says is there a way to use `NSSortDescriptor` to sort the results of a `NSFetchRequest` based on a specific attributes (that is a string) length with respect to number of characters?

For example
Order of results would be:

```
A
AA
AAA
AAAA
```

and so on

Thanks a lot everyone! I can't figure this one out

This is the sort descriptor i was trying:

```
NSSortDescriptor* sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"food_name" ascending:YES comparator:^(id obj1, id obj2) {
    NSInteger len1 = [obj1 length];
    NSInteger len2 = [obj2 length];
    if (len1 < len2) return NSOrderedAscending;
    if (len1 > len2) return NSOrderedDescending;
    return NSOrderedSame;
}];
```

I put a breakpoint in it and it doesn't seem to be getting called.

Comment: you should probably choose a better example. that's the exact sort order you'll get when sorting alphabetically. ;-)

Comment: Im pretty sure it's obvious enough of a question and since I don't say the word alphabetically once in it, I think I'm alright

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a sort descriptor with a custom comparator. Blocks make it really easy!

```
[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"stringName"
 ascending:YES
 comparator:^(id obj1, id obj2) {
    NSInteger len1 = [obj1 length];
    NSInteger len2 = [obj2 length];
    if (len1 < len2) return NSOrderedAscending;
    if (len1 > len2) return NSOrderedDescending;
    return NSOrderedSame;
 }];
```

Comment: Thats actually exactly what I was trying to do but for some reason it wasnt working. This is what I was using (check the edit in my original post)

Answer (score 1):

Just use the length as a key for the sort and add it with [setSortDescriptors:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSFetchRequest_Class/NSFetchRequest.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFetchRequest/setSortDescriptors%3a)

```
NSArray *example = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"AAAA", @"BBB", @"CC", @"D", nil];

NSSortDescriptor *lengthSorter = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"length" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:lengthSorter];

NSLog(@"%@", example);
NSLog(@"%@", [example sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors]);
```

Comment: To do this you need to fetch the data and then sort it in memory; it would be more efficient to let Core Data sort it by supplying the right sort descriptor with the fetch request.

Comment: The code was just an example of creating a sort descriptor, the  setSortDescriptors: link I provided shows how to add a sort descriptor to an NSFetchRequest.

Comment: @benzado Old answer, but your answer does not work with CoreData  *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'unsupported NSSortDescriptor (comparator blocks are not supported)'